# Docker не работает в фоновом режиме

Tags: docker

Прописал для Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["ping", "8.8.8.8"]
```

Все что хочу так это то чтобы команда ping работала в фоновом режиме.
Запускаю контейнер :

```
docker run -d test_ping sh
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы запустить ENTRYPOINT не нужно было передавать в аргументы sh и запускать без аргументов